# Android versions lower than API Level 21 using appcompat

Tags: android, android-appcompat

In the following code, `android:progressTint="#c9c9c9"`,  `android:secondaryProgressTint="#bebebe"` and `android:thumbTint="#a9a9a9"` are API Level 21 features. However, I am currently using `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1`. Will my app run on devices lower than API 21?

```
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/teacher_intro_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:progress="10"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:progressTint="#c9c9c9"
                android:secondaryProgressTint="#bebebe"
                android:thumbTint="#a9a9a9" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they will work for API 21 and above, For lower versions they will be ignored. If you want for all versions use app compat seekbar as below.

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/teacher_intro_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:progress="10"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    app:progressTint="#c9c9c9"
    app:secondaryProgressTint="#bebebe"
    app:thumbTint="#a9a9a9" />
```

Comment: According to the [official documentation][1], android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar "will automatically be used when you use SeekBar in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views."


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatSeekBar.html

Comment: How to use this approach with constraint layout or data binding, that already uses "app" name space. It says error: attribute progressTint not found

Answer (score 0):

It will run, but it may not look correct.  XML properties not recognized are ignored.  In this case they will definitely be ignored-  you aren't using an app compat version of Seekbar, so the compatibility library doesn't matter.  (I don't know  if there is an app compat version of seekbar, but even if there is you aren't using it).